# display opencv cv::Mat image in gtkmm

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gtk, gtkmm

I want to display a cv::Mat in a Gui written by gtkmm. So I have done a test.

I have a widget `Gtk::Image image`, and I want to set the image with the following two methods:

```
// first method, display from file
void displayImage1()
{
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pixbuf = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file("gtk.png");
    image.set(pixbuf);
}

// second method, display from cv::Mat
void displayImage2()
{
    cv::Mat outImage = cv::imread("gtk.png");
    cv::cvtColor(outImage, outImage, CV_BGR2RGB);
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pixbuf = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(outImage.data, Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB,false, 8, outImage.cols, outImage.rows, outImage.step);
    image.set(pixbuf);
}
```

The first method works well.

[image]

However, the second method doesn't work well, I got a destroyed image on the screen as shown in the picture.

[image]

If I set the has_alpha parameter to true, the result is also strange (see pic. below).
[image]

Similar tests were done by using Gtk::DrawingArea. Different IDEs are used (but all g++ compiler under linux). All same results.

Update:

I tested lots of images. Sometimes the images are broken, sometimes the programs crashed with

> The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: Have you checked that the image doesn't actually contain an alpha channel? Seems to me like it does unless the grey background is a part of the image.

Comment: @KjMag THANKS but the result with has_alpha as "true" is also not correct, I updated the result in the question.

Comment: 24 instead of 8 as "bits_per_sample"?

Comment: @Miki also tried, then it displays nothing(no correct image is created). Thank you!

Comment: The conversion code seems correct. I think that this is probably due the data buffer being release as soon as `outImage` goes out of scope at the end of the function. You need a way to actually copy the data inside the gtk image

Comment: @Miki Thank you I tried making the cv::Mat image as a member of my class which is initialized in the constructor and the two methods above are used as member functions. Nothing changed.

Comment: @Miki: `create_from_data` creates a copy of the bytes, and the copy is done before `outImage` goes out of scope...

Comment: @liberforce then I'm out of ideas ;)

Comment: @SummFang - I believe that the problem comes on some particularity about your image. You really got bad luck: I was stuck, I tested your code, and it does work with a Mat from cv::VideoCapture.read, on my Mac Os X with front camera.

Comment: @liberforce `create_from_data` **does not** create a copy. AFAIU it just wraps gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data, that does not copy anything: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm/-/blob/master/gdk/src/pixbuf.ccg#L60

Comment: @ntd: seems you're right, it creates a new GdkPixbuf object that merely references the existing memory. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

try add a reference to outimage, like **outimage.addref()** . all my problems were related to that. the source image being de-referenced before the **gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data** get a chance to map it. leading to segfaults, corruption and so on. just be sure to release it later, or use the callback provided with **gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data**

Answer (score 1):

For Gtkmm-2.4 and OpenCv 4.6 check https://onthim.blogspot.com/2015/10/using-opencv-in-gtk-applications.html and https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/2.24/sec-draw-images.html.es

```
    Mat frame;
    frame = imread("gtk.png");    
    cv::cvtColor (frame, frame, COLOR_BGR2RGB);//COLOR_BGR2GRAY
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> image = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(frame.data,Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB, false, 8, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step);
    image->render_to_drawable(get_window(), get_style()->get_black_gc(),0, 0, 0, 0, image->get_width(), image->get_height(), // draw the whole image (from 0,0 to the full width,height) at 100,80 in the window
Gdk::RGB_DITHER_NONE, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this kind of "broken" image trigger a warning in my head: "wrong rawstride !". The rawstride in `Gdk::Pixbuf` in the length in bytes of a line of data. That's because you may have some byte-alignment constraints, so there may be some padding at the end of one line.

I checked what this `step` argument was, and yes, that's the same in OpenCV as the rawstride in Gdk::Pixbuf. Until I realized `outImage.step` is a [`cv:MatStep`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d26/structcv_1_1MatStep.html) object, while `Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data` expects an int. I think you're supposed to use `outImage.step[0]` instead.

Please read https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat

Comment: a `cv::MatStep` is implicitly converted to a `size_t`, so it's ok to use `outImage.step` like this.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Yes I agree with @Miki . Nevertheless I tried with outImage.step[0], nothing changled.

Answer (score 0):

here we go:

```
auto lenna = imread("Lenna.png");
Image image;

cvtColor(lenna, lenna, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
auto size = lenna.size();
auto img = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(lenna.data, Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB, lenna.channels() == 4, 8, size.width, size.height, (int) lenna.step);

image.set(img);
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, but I think it is essentially the same as mine. I tried it anyhow and the result is the same. If it works on your side, it must be the problem of my compiler or system or the version of my library I don't know :(

Comment: I think the problem is that the version of the OpenCV and GTKmm are not the same. try gtkmm 2.4

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it show good result on image showing

```
cvtColor(resize_image, resize_image, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
Pixbuf = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(resize_image.data, Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB, false, 8, resize_image.cols, resize_image.rows, resize_image.step);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tested this (add scale_simple) with success for me:

From: http://orobotp.blogspot.com/2014/01/opencv-with-gtkmm3.html

Version: Gtkmm 3.22.2-2, OpenCV 4.4.0-dev, g++ 7.5.0

```
void displayImage2()
{
    cv::Mat outImage;
    outImage = cv::imread("gtk.png");
    cv::cvtColor(outImage, outImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pixbuf = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(outImage.data, Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB,false, 8, outImage.cols, outImage.rows, outImage.step)->scale_simple( outImage.cols, outImage.rows, Gdk::INTERP_BILINEAR );
    image.set(pixbuf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, as already suggested by @Miki in the comments, this is just a lifetime issue.

I had the very same problem with similar code:

```
{
    cv::Mat rgb;
    cv::cvtColor(src, rgb, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data(rgb.data,
                                      GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8,
                                      rgb.cols, rgb.rows, rgb.step,
                                      NULL, NULL);
}
```

The above snippet simply does not work (or works intermittently) because, quoting the [`gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data` documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk-pixbuf/ctor.Pixbuf.new_from_bytes.html), "the data is owned by the caller of the function".

The problem is at the time the image is rendered, `rgb` has been destroyed. Adding a `rgb.addref()` just before the `pixbuf` assignment resolves the issue, although introducing a memory leak.

One solution would be to leverage the destroy callback to unreference the `Mat` object, e.g.:

```
static void
unref_mat(guchar *data, gpointer user_data)
{
    ((cv::Mat *) user_data)->release();
}

{
    cv::Mat rgb;
    cv::cvtColor(src, rgb, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    rgb.addref()
    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data(rgb.data,
                                      GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8,
                                      rgb.cols, rgb.rows, rgb.step,
                                      unref_mat, &rgb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cv::Mat **outImage** will be distroyed when excution run out of the scope of the function **displayImage2()**, thus you should declare the variable **outImage** in your custom class which derived from **Gtk::Window**. Here is a example worked fine with gtkmm4 and opencv4:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <gtkmm.h>

class Buttons : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
  Buttons();
  virtual ~Buttons();

protected:
  cv::Mat outImage;
  Gtk::Image image;
};

Buttons::Buttons()
{
  outImage = cv::imread("gtk.jpg");
  cv::cvtColor(outImage, outImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
  Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pixbuf = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(outImage.data,
                                                                   Gdk::Colorspace::RGB,
                                                                   false, 
                                                                   8, 
                                                                   outImage.cols, 
                                                                   outImage.rows, 
                                                                   outImage.step);
  image.set(pixbuf);
  set_child(image);
}

Buttons::~Buttons()
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.example");

  //Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
  return app->make_window_and_run<Buttons>(argc, argv);
}
```